# Capistrano cannot deploy code, because Net::SSH::AuthenticationFailed: Authentication failed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, ssh, capistrano

We have a Rails app that is running on Amazon AWS. We're pushing there a new code almost every day for a few months in a row.

Today, when I tried to deploy a new code there, I was given this error message:

```
  * 2014-02-16 13:09:51 executing `deploy'
  * 2014-02-16 13:09:51 executing `deploy:update'
 ** transaction: start
  * 2014-02-16 13:09:51 executing `deploy:update_code'
    updating the cached checkout on all servers
    executing locally: "git ls-remote git@bitbucket.org:my_bitbucket_name/project_name.git master"
    command finished in 2909ms
  * executing "if [ -d /home/deployer/project_name/shared/cached-copy ]; then cd /home/deployer/project_name/shared/cached-copy && git fetch -q origin && git fetch --tags -q origin && git reset -q --hard 16958dfcee27dd9c33855ecece0013428e2c57c8 && git clean -q -d -x -f; else git clone -q -b master git@bitbucket.org:rdudacz/looky.co.git /home/deployer/looky/shared/cached-copy && cd /home/deployer/project_name/shared/cached-copy && git checkout -q -b deploy 16958dfcee27dd9c33855ecece0013428e2c57c8; fi"
    servers: ["IP"]
*** [deploy:update_code] rolling back
  * executing "rm -rf /home/deployer/project_name/releases/20140216120957; true"
    servers: ["IP"]
 ** [deploy:update_code] exception while rolling back: Capistrano::ConnectionError, connection failed for: IP (Net::SSH::AuthenticationFailed: Authentication failed for user deployer@IP)
connection failed for: IP (Net::SSH::AuthenticationFailed: Authentication failed for user deployer@IP)
```

What happened here? Where to start with looking for the issue?

Answer (score 23):

The problem is the gem

> net-ssh

The last version (2.8.0) causes this issue. The solution is to uninstall it:

```
gem uninstall net-ssh -v 2.8.0
```

and then to add to the Gemfile its previous version:

```
gem "net-ssh", "~> 2.7.0"
```

That's it.

Comment: I am `Using net-ssh 2.7.0` and passwordless login is working fine, but still getting `Net::SSH::AuthenticationFailed`

Comment: Thanks you! It seems that 2.9 also has an issue where it can't connect  to the server via port 22, while using ssh works fine. Reverting to 2.7 works!

Comment: I'm using ruby-2.1.2p95, after installing net-ssh 2.7.0, I got this error: **/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:298:in `to_specs': Could not find 'net-ssh' (>= 2.8.0) - did find: [net-ssh-2.7.0] (Gem::LoadError)

Comment: I am using net-ssh 2.7.0 and got the same issue

Answer (score 10):

I had the same problem while deploying using capistrano 
Net::SSH::AuthenticationFailed: Authentication failed for user deployer@IP

```
ssh-copy-id deployer@ip
```

This will add your keys to server and you can login without password.

Answer (score 0):

After uninstall net-ssh 2.8.0, remove on gemfile.lock, too. It will continuously okay.

Answer (score 0):

Please remove old net-ssh and install updated as below, add this in your gem file or can install it on your environment specifying 2.9.2 version.

```
gem 'net-ssh', '~> 2.9.2'
```

Its works for me.

Answer (score 0):

For capistrano2 in your deploy.rb

- net-ssh 2.9.1 set `:ssh_options, { config: false}`
- net-ssh 2.9.2 set `:ssh_options, { config: false, number_of_password_prompts: 0 }`